# Critique: Looking For Honest Feedback On A Logo Sketch

Tags: logo, critique, identity

A little intro: Graphic Design isn't really my thing and the last time I did design was back in 2007... until today that we need to brand our new wedding videography studio. Because of budget constraints, I had to try my hand again to pencil in a logo (will go through the trouble of relearning Illustrator later on).

After numerous concepts, this is the sketch that my partner liked the most.

I have been gathering feedback from friends and I'll be definitely looking forward for any unbiased feedback from experts like you. For example, I'd like to know:

1. What are the top keywords/message that pop in your mind when you saw
   the logo (albeit still a sketch)?
2. What letters, in your opinion, are visible? (I'm going for the easy readability of the logo)
3. Are there any logos you have seen that is too similar to this one? (If so, I will take it into consideration and modify the logo)
4. Where do you think I should improve on/any advice to improve

This is the sketch I am talking about (Sorry for the hastily shot and unprocessed image):
[image]

Thank you for your time - take care! :)

Comment: I personally see "SDV" the line from the D to the V suggests and S-like shape.

Comment: One logo it (remotely) reminds me of is https://www.google.com/search?q=ge+logo&oq=ge+logo&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j69i60l2j0.1015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Pekka웃 - this is a good point! thanks for sharing - I'm wary of having this look much GE myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good job!

> What are the top keywords/message that pop in your mind when you saw
>   the logo (albeit still a sketch)?

I second @DA01 - it does not matter, really. What it does have, is "swooshiness" and elegance. As the sketch is right now, it is too "heavy", too dark. But that of course will change.

> What letters, in your opinion, are visible? (I'm going for the easy
>   readability of the logo)

I have no problem seeing DV; to me there is no S in there.

> Are there any logos you have seen that is too similar to this one? (If
>   so, I will take it into consideration and modify the logo)

No, not to my knowledge.

> Where do you think I should improve on/any advice to improve

I think this is pretty solid work as it is.

What I would keep in mind though, is to make the final one fairly light. And with that I mean subtle choice of colours, easy on (if any) shadows, outlines, accompanying fonts etc.

This because of the wedding-thing; you want colours that does not take away too much from what will likely be classic wedding colours such as cream, pastels, white, lace-ish etc.

The thing is: many people want - and associate - cream, white, pastels with weddings: the traditional choice of colours. What I do think you manage here, is to also capture the potential for less traditionally-minded clients. A very good thing.

But this all stands or falls on the final colouring and in what context. If you are going to use this as watermark too, I think that will work nicely.

Keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am learning a lot from your  comment! We definitely want to steer clear from the traditional and mostly cliche designs we saw when we did an analysis of our "competition/peers". The palette will be a bit earthy since we'll be targetting jetsetter/adventurous couples, with a bit of copper (for the logo), charcoal and maybe tinted hues of green or turquoise for accent. But we haven't finalized it yet but that's the look and feel we're after. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Aha! Brilliant! Sounds like a good plan :) good luck.

Comment: It's very ambitious, but we hope we can pull it off :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Keywords: complete, business, serious, artistic
2. I see: D, V
3. None exactly like this as far as I know.
4. I would try removing the "leg going to left side" at the bottom part of letter D, that is a little detail that I do like the least about it.

---

All answers are based on my personal experience, I am no expert :-) Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much for your input and your time for answering! :) 

I'm glad the keywords you've mentioned are close to what I had in mind when sketching the logo. I'll definitely try a variation of it using your suggestions! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Answers:

1. Interesting, sophisticated
2. D,V
3. I've seen similar style but it's rare.
4. I don't like the vertical straight line of the D. The symbol can be drawn by a continuous line, except that line. Overall it's an interesting logo but I also feel that the final execution is very crucial. This kind of logos can look really stylish or really cheap, with a thin line between the two.
   While looking at it, I made this idea. Use it if you find something in it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm now taking notes of your input - I definitely appreciate the logo concept you've sent too! Regarding the final execution, I agree, and I've got to admit, the last time I opened AI was in 2007 so I'm kind of overwhelmed with it.

Thanks again! :D

Comment: @rustydesignerr Don't rush it. I think the first idea is always the worst. Our mind wants to solve problems fast and usually spits out what's barely enough to cover the task. If this is your first idea just leave it somewhere and focus on it later. The initial excitement would settle and you will take a more rational decision.

Comment: Sound advice! I'll definitely let it percolate in my head a bit and look at it at a later time with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the top keywords/message that pop in your mind when you saw the logo (albeit still a sketch)?

It doesn't really matter. What matters is if it's appropriate for your needs. I think it is. It feels like it works for an elegant wedding photographer.

> What letters, in your opinion, are visible? (I'm going for the easy readability of the logo)

D&V

> Are there any logos you have seen that is too similar to this one? (If so, I will take it into consideration and modify the logo)

In your local wedding photographer market? None that I know of. :)

> Where do you think I should improve on/any advice to improve

It's solid as-is, IMHO. But you could certainly start working on how you might incorporate type into (along with) it.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! :) Some friends have told me that the logo looked similar to logos like Mazda etc, so I thought it's also good to ask professionals. As for incorporating type, I'm planning on using Gotham (probably medium, or probably any solid sans serif) to contrast the circular logo a bit? What do you think? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Unless you are infringing on the Mazda logo (which you are not, IMHO) then I see no conflict...few people are shopping for wedding photographers at the same time they are shopping for used cars. As for Gotham, it's great. Perhaps over-used, but if it works, it works!

Answer (score 2):

Good job! I see A and D, and the style feels luxurious and a bit romantic. I like the idea of a ribbon, but I would make it continuous, e.g. removing the parts that sticks out from the D. I made a really quick and dirty mockup of what I had on my mind :)

[image]

Comment: You could refine it further by making the loop behind the D:s back a bit smaller to enhance the letter D.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I'll definitely adjust the loop behind the D. I'm jealous of your vector skills, wish I could do that! I deliberately sketched the logo to make it easy for me to create it on Illustrator. Hears to hoping my brain learns the Pen Tool on time! Thanks again for your time! :D

Comment: oops. *here's to hoping.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clean and feels like it would speak well to a wedding photography business. Keep in mind that for any logo, it is how it is used (in your case, as a watermark on a photo perhaps, or on an envelope of prints) that reinforces/creates meaning. I think you're on the right track with feel, readability, and distinctiveness.

Answer (score 2):

I really like your sketch so far, but I think user23248 has a good point about it being used as a watermark on a video/photo. With that in mind, I think you might want to add something to it "DV Photography" "DV Videography" etc. You could just add the "Photography/Videography" below the DV in an italics and much smaller font.

What color are you wanting to work with?

If you want someone else to do your logo in AI for you (for FREE) let me know. I am trying to build up my portfolio as I have one final semester of University before I'm in the real world! :) If you want my help, just let me know and I will get you my contact info.

Answer (score 0):

I really love this Sketch! One thing I noticed is that I feel like the V is leaning a bit to the left. I think if you moved the cross of the loop on the right a bit more over the v could open more symmetrical